# How do I insert a row into numbers, in just one column

Tags: numbers

How do I insert a row in one column only. By moving the current data down and inserting a row above it. I don't want to insert a row across the entire spreadsheet - just that column.

Answer (score 4):

From Numbers help:

> Move rows and columns within a table Select one or more rows or
>   columns.
>
> Do any of the following:
>
> Move rows: After selecting the rows, click and hold the row numbers
>   until the rows appear to rise off the table, then drag them above or
>   below another row.
>
> Move columns: After selecting the columns, click and hold the column
>   letters until the columns appear to rise off the table, then drag them
>   to the right or left of another column.
>
> Tip: If you drag rows or columns outside of an existing table, you
>   create a new table with them.

This has plagued me for ages and I took to forums to unsuccessfully find the answer, till I finally used the help function found in Numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In excel it is no brainier, just use copy and Insert and it will asks you to move that row up or down.

In Numbers I found [this answer here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2041655).

> Numbers and Excel are built on different frameworks in the sense that
>   an Excel table/spreadsheet is virtually boundless and Numbers tables
>   are finite and generally only as large as the data requires. Pushing
>   some cells out of the way to make room for others has greater
>   implications in Numbers, and it is left to the user to make room by
>   moving the cells manually. I once counted mouse clicks to achieve the
>   insertion in Numbers vs. Excel and the difference was small to none.
>   Yes, Excel will move cells for you, but not until you tell it which
>   way to move them. With Numbers you just do it yourself.
>
> There's a nifty command pair in Numbers that helps with the job. It is
>   +Mark for Move+ and Move.
>
> Select the cells to be moved, Edit > Mark for Move, click to select
>   the cell where you want the upper left cell of the range to move to
>   and then Edit > Move.

Comment: Gone in the current version. :(

Comment: Not an answer but, This has rendered Numbers useless to me as I often add internal rows in spreadsheets and need o move existing rows up or down without affecting other columns.